# WPF Adding a ComboBox to a DataGrid or List View Based on different DB Tables

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid, combobox

I would like to add a `ComboBox` to a `DataGrid` or `ListView` but the Combobox's underlying `ViewSource` would be filtered by data from each row's `DataRowView` of the `DataGrid`.

Example:

A list of companies and some information about the company is displayed in a `DataGrid`/`ListView`. The companies listed may have several phone numbers. I want the phone numbers to be in the `ComboBox` that is displayed with the companies information.
The company information and phone numbers are in different tables and the binding Mode would only be one way for all data.

Or is there a better way to display the data?

Thanks!!

Comment: Each company may have several phone numbers? Is that the purpose of the combobox?

Comment: Yes. So the user can choose the phone number they want to use without having a row in the `datagrid` for each phone numbers.

Comment: Your approach sounds fine to me.

Comment: I'm unfarmiliar with the term `ViewSource` in the context of `ComboBox`. do you mean `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
     <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </ie:EventTrigger>
    </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCompanyPhoneNumbers}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItemChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>((selectedItem) => 
        {
            var selected = selectedItem as Company;

            SelectedCompanyPhoneNumbers = selected.CompanyPhoneNumbers;
        });
    }

    public view LoadCompanies()
    {
        // Load the companies information from different tables ...
    }

    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<object> SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public List<string> SelectedCompanyPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<string> CompanyPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I used Prism framework in this example. The `i` and `ie` are shortcuts to namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

What happens here is that the viewModel holds a list of the selected company phone numbers. Whenever the company gets changed (a different row in the grid get's selected in this example) the selected company's phone numbers is changed accordingly.

Here are some good links on MVVM:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Good luck

Comment: Would this not display all the phone numbers for all companies in the `CompanyPhoneNumbers` `Column/ComboBox`. If the first row in the `DataGrid` has information about company ABC Inc. I want only to display the phone numbers for that company not all the companies.

Comment: @user2378527 Then you don't want the ComboBox as a column but as a single control in your view.. I'll update my answer one moment please ...

Comment: @user2378527 does this answer your needs?

Comment: So you would have just one `ComboBox` and update it based on which `row`/company the user selected? If I went this way could I not just use the `SelectedCellsChanged` and filter the `ComboBox's ViewSource` based on the rows `DataRowView` data?

Comment: @user2378527 That is exactly what is happening here, only in MVVM using Bindings and Commands and not Code-Behind event handlers, and reacting to `SelectionChanged` instead of `SelectedCellsChanged` ...

Comment: I am not very familiar with MVVM but my assumption is that not using the 'Code-Behind' would be the better way to go.

Comment: @user2378527 you should REALLY get familiar with MVVM. it's good, it's way powerful, and it's SO damn useful. There is a learning curve but you should definitly start climbing that hill if you want to do stuff right :)

Comment: I know I'm suppose to avoid comments like Thanks but THANKS Omribitan!!